# A question was put on hold, but gained an answer about thirty minutes later

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

I closed the following question at 2016-04-10 11:36:57Z as off-topic:
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49269/4945
Yet about thirty minutes later, at 2016-04-10 12:05:02Z, it received an answer. You can follow that in the [timeline](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/49269/timeline/).

What happened?

Comment: [status-by-design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible), see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/271002

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loong hit this earlier than me. [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)

Sometimes when you put the computer to sleep, or are on mobile, or do whatever else so you pass the client based restriction of not being able to add the answer after the question was closed, you can still post your answer for as long as 4 hours after the question being closed, because the server still accepts it.

<punchline> Let's close them faster. （ノ≧∇≦）ノ ɥoɯǝʍoɹʞ bnǝsʇᴉous <\punchline>

Comment: I closed this question within three minutes... I'm not the flash... can't do it any faster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure even Flash can't do it, with a slow internet. Good news is, from what I've seen, people don't deliberately try to bypass it and it's almost always honest mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As per one of the many SE updates that happened since this question, this can no longer happen. People composing answers will now immediately be notified if the underlying question has been closed.

Comment: Just tested on the main site: it can still happen.

Comment: Did you find that out through experience or did you read about this anywhere?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thing is, I don’t know about a high-entry trick (re-enable the post answer button). Without that trick, answering is prohibited as I experienced on other SE e.g. yesterday.